# Push currentUser's ID to inner Array of a collection/ document in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

```
{
    "_id" : "s2QBCnv6fXv5YbjAP",
    "question" : "Is this real change?",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-05-13T21:05:23.381Z"),
    "yes" : [
            {
                    "heading" : "Yes It is",
                    "body" : "I think this government knows what they are doing. That's why there has not been any form of protest",
                    "email" : "I think this government knows what they are doing. That's why there has not been any form of protest",
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-05-13T21:08:25.119Z"),
                    "replies" : [ ],
                    "likes" : [ ]
            },
            {
                    "heading" : "Well, Yes",
                    "body" : "I think this is change as we all want to know what the government is doing and I am grateful to be alive at this time",
                    "email" : "I think this is change as we all want to know what the government is doing and I am grateful to be alive at this time",
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-05-13T21:10:47.123Z"),
                    "replies" : [ ],
                    "likes" : [ ]
            }
    ],
    "no" : [
            {
                    "heading" : "Not at All",
                    "body" : "This is not the change I wanted. This is waste of four years and I amm waiting to see the promised change",
                    "email" : "kenshin@kay.com",
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-05-13T21:12:58.977Z"),
                    "replies" : [ ],
                    "likes" : [ ]
            }
    ],
    "author" : "admin",
    "image" : "/cfs/files/QuestionImages/DzdpK6NdurZMTwAse"
```

}

Hi all, I'm quite new to MeteorJs and I'm working on an app. i would like to know how to update the "likes" array. I want to push the currentUser's Id into the likes so on the front-end I will display yes.objectsReference.likes.length as the number of likes.

How can i target the likes array? thanks

Comment: Your going to have problems working with arrays in [arrays in mongodb.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783896/mongodb-updating-an-array-in-array).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`$`** positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/update/positional/) on the server to update the likes array. Suppose you want to add the current user id to the likes array on the embedded "Yes" document with "heading" value "Well, Yes", then the following shows how you can do it on the server:

```
Articles.update(
    {
        "_id" : "s2QBCnv6fXv5YbjAP",
        "yes.heading" : "Well, Yes"
    },
    {
        "$push": { "yes.$.likes": userId }
    }
)
```